# Case to get if the employee doesn't have an active employer, then give me a null employer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables: Employee, Employer, and Employment History. I'm looking to get a list of employees, with their most recent full-time employer, if they have an active full-time record.

Say I have the following Employment History table:

```
Employee ID | Employer ID | Start Date | End Date  | Status
---------------------------------------------------------------
  1         |  AA         |  1/1/2019  |           | Part-Time
  1         |  BB         |  1/1/2000  |           | Full-Time
  2         |  CC         |  3/1/2019  |           | Part-Time
  2         |  DD         |  3/1/2000  | 5/15/2021 | Full-Time
```

And Employees with IDs 1, 2, and 3.

Here's where I start:

```
select employee.id, employer.id 
from Employee employee left join EmploymentHistory eh on eh.employeeId = employee.id 
left join Employer employer on eh.employerId = employer.id
```

But I don't know how to say if the employee doesn't have an active employer, then give me a null employer ID. If they have an active (as in no end date) employment history record that is full-time, give me the most recent of those, and if they don't have an active full-time record, then give me the most recent part-time one.

I started going into loops with sub queries and trying to select based on max start date, and I'm all sorts of turned around.

In the end, I'd like the results to look something like this:

```
Employee ID | Employer ID 
---------------------------
  1         |  BB         |
  2         |  CC         |
  3         |  <null>     |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `OUTER APPLY` and a subquery that fetches the top record for each employee according to the type and end of the employment.

```
SELECT e.id,
       x.employerid
       FROM employee e
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                                eh.employerid
                                FROM employmenthistory eh
                                WHERE eh.employeeid = e.id
                                      AND eh.status IN ('Full-Time',
                                                        'Part-Time')
                                ORDER BY eh.status ASC,
                                         eh.enddate DESC) x;
```

Comment: I will need to double check my return results but on first inspection, it looks like this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to get a list of employees, with their most recent full-time employer, if they have an active full-time record.

You can just use one table:

```
select eh.*
from (select eh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by startdate desc) as seqnum
      from EmploymentHistory eh
      where status = 'Full-Time'
     ) eh
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Will that give me the part-time record if there is no full-time record, and give me employees that don't have any Employment History records?

Comment: @Risu why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @DaleK, I have tried it as you suggested and all my returned records are only Full-Time.

Comment: @Risu . . . No, because that is not what the question asks:  "I'm looking to get a list of employees, with their most recent full-time employer, if they have an active full-time record."  This answers the actual question you asked.